# Regex in which the first character should not be dash (-) but dash can be in middle of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is the RegEx:

```
/(?!(.)\1+$)(?!.*(.)\2{2})(?!.*( |'|-)\3{1})(?=\S*(\s\S*){0,4}$)(?=[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ .]*(['-][a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ .]*){0,2}$)(?=(.*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ.]){2}.*$)^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯЁёè-ÿ '-]{2,25}$/,
```

I was trying to make a RegEx in which the first character should not be dash (-) but dash (-) can be there in the string and there shouldn't be consecutive dashes.

Comment: Your regex is wrong. Please provide all the requirements. I understood your [regex works like this](https://regex101.com/r/zrfbiH/1). Do you need it to [work like this](https://regex101.com/r/zrfbiH/2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The regex should accept English, Cyrillic & Symbol: - (dash) like Alberto Santos-Dumont

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but it should not accept -Alberto or - -Alberto but should accept Alberto-Santos

Comment: Try my second link and let know if it works.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i tried your second link but it should not accept Alberto- -Alberto

Comment: Please add all the requirements to the question. It is not a good idea to make others guess what you need.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/zrfbiH/4

Comment: It should not accept Alberto- -Alberto, Alberto, -Alberto,- -Alberto.

Comment: These are examples, not requirements, please add *requirements* to the question, do not add just samples in the comments. Why shouldn't it accept `Alberto`? Another guess - https://regex101.com/r/zrfbiH/5

Comment: It should not accept Alberto- -Alberto, Alberto, -Alberto,- -Alberto.But it should accept English, Cyrillic & Symbol: - (dash) like Alberto Santos-Dumont.Alberto means(Space Alberto).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: `/^[^\-]((?![\-]{2,}).)+$/`?